# NSPredicate for range between two dates is not working as expected

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, nspredicate

I have these two `NSDate`s:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
NSDate *rangeStart = [df dateFromString: @"03/03/2013"];
NSDate *rangeEnd = [df dateFromString: @"10/04/2013"];
```

And this predicate:

```
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"createdDate >= %@ AND createdDate <= %@", rangeStart, rangeEnd];
```

But even though the second part of the predicate specifically uses a `<=` it is returning objects up until the day before (that is `10/03/2013`).

I also tried constructing the predicate like this:

```
NSPredicate *dateStartPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"createdDate >= %@", rangeStart];
NSPredicate *dateEndPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"createdDate <= %@", rangeEnd];
NSPredicate *finalPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:dateStartPredicate, dateEndPredicate, nil]];
```

But I'm getting the same results. Am I doing something wrong? Is this actually the expected behavior? If it is, how can set the `rangeEnd` to the next day?

Thanks

Comment: This worked for me.         NSPredicate *dateStartPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"timeStamp >= %@", pastDate];
        NSPredicate *dateEndPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"timeStamp <= %@", nowDate];
        NSPredicate *finalPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:dateStartPredicate, dateEndPredicate, nil]];

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`NSDate` objects include the time as well. When you pass a date with no time to the `dateFromString:` method, the midnight of the corresponding day is assumed, i.e. only the items that happen on midnight would return `true` in the less than or equal expression.

There are two common ways of solving it:

- Add one day to `rangeEnd`, and use "less than" instead of "less than or equal", or
- Add the time to the `rangeEnd` date (this is not ideal, because you would either need to specify the time in a long string, or miss the items that happened on the last second of the day).

Here is how to use the first approach:

```
request.predicate = [NSPredicate
    predicateWithFormat:@"createdDate >= %@ AND createdDate < %@"
    , rangeStart
    , [rangeEnd dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24]
];
```

Comment: Thanks for the description, didn't know this. But did you see the end of my question? `If it is, how can set the rangeEnd to the next day?`could you elaborate on that please? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Remember that even though the name of the class is NSDate, these objects represent specific points in time (not an entire day).  `rangeEnd` is set to midnight of October 4th.  Since midnight is the first instant of that day, only events at midnight of that day will be included in your results.  Move `rangeEnd` to the next day as shown below and you should get the results you expect.

```
NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];
NSDateComponents* components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
components.day = 1;
NSDate* newDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:rangeEnd options: 0];
```

Comment: Thanks for the description, didn't know this. But did you see the end of my question? `If it is, how can set the rangeEnd to the next day?`could you elaborate on that please? Thanks

Comment: @Jan This method takes into account leap seconds and all sorts of things where a day might not necessarily equal 24*60*60 seconds.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I ended up using @dasblinkenlight answer because of simplicity and he answered first. But I did upvote your answer though. Thanks!